# Mongoose Error Handling duplication in save()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to reduce the code duplication. The problem came when I started with the mongoose error. I have 6 functions that uses the same mongoose `save()` method. On every save I check the errors and I have switch with 4 cases and this block is repeated in every function that uses the save method.

What's the best way to make it with only one function?

1. Should I overwrite the save method and pass the response interface to the overwritten method and response with the error. But actually it's not a valid in same cases (if some errors are thrown I should do something else, not to response the user with the validation error). I was thinking to create one global object with the errors (key: code error, value: the error that I have to send to the user).
2. Or it's not bad practice to repeat the handling error switch?

This is the repeating code

```
if (err) {
    if (err.name == 'ValidationError' && err.errors.username && err.errors.username.kind == 'unique')
            return reply('This username is already taken');
    else if (err.name == 'ValidationError' && err.errors.email && err.errors.email.kind == 'unique')
        return reply('There is already a user with this email');
    return callback(err);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code snippets?

Comment: As long as the error handling functions don't have any side effects, you can pass around same functions.

Comment: so it's not a problem to pass the response interface to the save method?

Comment: yes its not. Be sure to check that it doesn't change any global variables